# Insert an image in a particular position, python

Tags: python, insert-image

Good morning, 
I need to insert dynamically in image in a particular place in a background image, for example, I calculate the coordination of a rectangle and then I want to place a picture in the exact place of that rectangle.
**Parts of my code :**

```
filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")])
image=cv2.imread(filename,1)
filename1 = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("image","*.png")]) #Inserted img
img=cv2.imread(filename1,1)

#to calculate the cordination/width and height of the rectangle
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

offset = np.array((x,y))
image[offset[0]:offset[0]+img.shape[0],offset[1]:offset[1]+img.shape[1]] = img
```

I'm not very familiar with the way `offset` works, So can you please help me understand it in order to achieve my goal.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the `c` variable?

Comment: the `c` variable is from the for loop that I created in order to do the shape detection( It has nothing to do with my problem with the localisation of the image, I guess !!)

Comment: I just should have put `offset = np.array((y,x))`  instead of `offset = np.array((x,y))`
 Thank you